# Carolina Reaper and Scorpion pepper leaves yellow and spotty?

Tags: diseases, peppers

So I planted a couple of Carolina Reaper(bottom two pictures) and scorpion pepper (top picture) plants in my garden this year. I transplanted them outdoors around a month ago today. I'm not super familiar with them as it is my first year growing them myself. I know the older leaves tend to turn yellow and you can pick them off but, in this case, the whole plant looks yellow in color. I also noticed some gray and black spots on the leaves. I haven't really seen something like that before.

I don't believe it is an under-watering issue. I don't believe it is nutrient deficient either because I have several other pepper plants growing two to three feet over with nice dark green leaves. (But I suppose it still could be?) I am in Zone 7 and we haven't had any frost since March (before they were outdoors).

I've included some pictures below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Scorpion]
[image: Reaper1]
[image: Reaper2]